# CDMA : Calculating M from m1 * w1, m2*w2, etc M as Walsh Code, M as Orthogonal COde

Tags: frequency-spectrum, convolution

I have these values,

m2 = 1 -1 -1 1
w2 =-1 -1 1 1    -1 -1 1 1    -1 -1 1 1    -1 -1 1 1

Im about to multiply m2 with w2

Should i multiply m2 with all of w2
(1 * -1 -1 1 1    -1 -1 1 1    -1 -1 1 1    -1 -1 1 1)
(-1 * -1 -1 1 1    -1 -1 1 1    -1 -1 1 1    -1 -1 1 1)
(-1 * -1 -1 1 1    -1 -1 1 1    -1 -1 1 1    -1 -1 1 1)
(1 * -1 -1 1 1    -1 -1 1 1    -1 -1 1 1    -1 -1 1 1)

Or do it one by one,
(1 * -1 -1 1 1)
(-1 * -1 -1 1 1),
...
..

Which one is correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with @MattL when he says that the OP could have given more detail.

There are two different ways of interpreting what the OP has said, and the first,
which is the one chosen by Matt, is that the spreading code $w2$ is actually just 
$$-1\ -1\ +1\ +1$$ and what is happening is that the spreading code or its complement is repeated $4$ times ($4$ being the length of the message $m2$), 
with choice of whether $+w2$ or $-w2$ is used depending on whether the corresponding "bit"
in $m2$ is $+1$ or $-1$. In other words, the result is just
$$\begin{array}{cccc}m2=+1&m2=-1&m2=-1&m2=+1\\
\Downarrow&\Downarrow&\Downarrow&\Downarrow\\
+w2&-w2&-w2&+w2\\
\overbrace{-1\ -1\ +1\ +1}
&\overbrace{+1\ +1\ -1\ -1}
&\overbrace{+1\ +1\ -1\ -1}
&\overbrace{-1\ -1\ +1\ +1}
\end{array}$$
Also, no *multiplication* is really necessary regardless of whether the
calculation is being done in software or hardware since the whole process
can be implemented using `if-then-else` statements or multiplexers as the 
case may be.
Finally, for *this* particular $w2$, if *sketching* the waveform
using rectangular NRZ pulses will show that the end result is really
just *Manchester coding* of the data.

The *other* interpretation is similar to what has been said above
except that $w2$ really is what the OP says it is, *viz.*,
$$-1\ -1\ +1\ +1\ -1\ -1\ +1\ +1\ -1\ -1\ +1\ +1\ -1\ -1\ +1\ +1$$
and so that the spreading factor is $16$ and
each $\pm 1$ in $m2$ results in the $16$-symbol $\pm w2$.

$$\scriptscriptstyle{\begin{array}{cccc}m2=+1&m2=-1&m2=-1&m2=+1\\
\Downarrow&\Downarrow&\Downarrow&\Downarrow\\
+w2&-w2&-w2&+w2\\
\overbrace{-1\ -1\ +1\ +1\ -1\ -1\ +1\ +1\ -1\ -1\ +1\ +1\ -1\ -1\ +1\ +1}
&\overbrace{+1\ +1\ -1\ -1\ +1\ +1\ -1\ -1\ +1\ +1\ -1\ -1\ +1\ +1\ -1\ -1}
&\overbrace{+1\ +1\ \cdots\ -1\ -1}
&\overbrace{-1\ -1\ \cdots\ +1\ +1}
\end{array}}$$
The previous remarks about no multiplications being necessary are still
applicable, though the result is no longer just simple Manchester coding.
Note , however, that the *Sylvester construction* of the $16\times 16$
Hadamard matrix $H_{16}$ gives
$$H_{16}=\left[\begin{matrix}
H_4&H_4&H_4&H_4\\
H_4&-H_4&H_4&-H_4\\
H_4&H_4&-H_4&-H_4\\
H_4&-H_4&-H_4&H_4\\\end{matrix}\right]$$
and since the third row of $H_4$ is $+1\ +1\ -1\ -1$, the third row
of $H_{16}$ is just $-w2$.

Comment: I use the H16, so i think your second answer is correct. Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

You could have given a bit more background and explanation in your question, but as far as I understand your question, $m2$ is your data and $w2$ is the spreading code. The spreading ratio is 4 because the length of the spreading sequence is four times the data length. So you have to stretch out your data by a factor of 4 to line it up with the spreading sequence. Then you can do the multiplication as follows:

$$\begin{array}{rrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr}m2: & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1
& -1 & -1 & -1 & -1 & -1 & -1 & -1 & -1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
w2: & -1 & -1 & 1 & 1& -1 & -1 & 1 & 1& -1 & -1 & 1 & 1& -1 & -1 & 1 & 1\\
\text{result}:
& -1 & -1 &1&1&1&1&-1&-1&1&1&-1&-1&-1&-1&1&1\end{array}$$

Comment: The w2 is  -1 -1 1 1 -1 -1 1 1 -1 -1 1 1 -1 -1 1 1, Its not -1 -1 1 1 (4 times).

I'm using H16